# Android emulator for games

Tags: games, android, emulation

I have tried different Android emulators for playing mobile games. I tried wine too but those emulators are buggy for me. There is nothing which I found apt for this purpose. Is there anybody who plays high-end mobile games in Ubuntu? Please help!

Comment: Have you tried installing Android in a virtual machine? https://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/